# how to map two different objects and display in ag-grid in angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am providing the sample working data and having two objects

```
vlist=[
  {

    "city": "Mumbai",
    "offers": {
      "1": {
        "status": "true",
        "price": 100
      },
      "2": {
        "status": "true",
        "price": 100
      }
    }
  }
]

products=[
  {
    "productID": 1,
    "productName": "pespsi"
  },
  {
    "productID": 2,
    "productName": "coke
  },
  {
    "productID": 3,
    "productName": "thubs up"
  }

]
```

In the above provided objects I need to map the product name with product id in products objects with respective objects in the "vlist". and my main objective is how to display those values using ag-grid.

Here is my column def:

```
columnDefs = [{
    headerName: 'productname', field: 'productname', filter: true, resizable: true
  },{
    headerName: 'price', field: 'price', filter: true, resizable: true
  }, {
    headerName: 'status', field: 'status', filter: true, resizable: true
  }
];
```

Expecting result like this:

```
productname     price    status
pespsi          100      true
coke            100      true
thumbsup        100      true
```

Vlist like this:

```
vlist=[
  {

    "city": "Mumbai",
    "offers": {
      "pespsi": {
        "status": "true",
        "price": 100
      },
      "coke": {
        "status": "true",
        "price": 100
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the expected object? Give an example of what it should look like when merged.

Comment: Actaully I looking to map the boh objects with the ID nubers and display the result

Comment: Yes I understand that you want the objects together but in which form, what the object should look like when merged? For example, the product needs to be a property inside the vlist, the vlist with the right id should be in the product?

Comment: I have provided my expected result. Kindly just tell what steps should I make to achieve it

Comment: @ukn Provided expected result is clear right for your query

Comment: Is vList's offers a map?

Comment: @ukn   I didn't get the point. I just need to replace the number with product name in the vlist object . Dont know how to display in the ag grid table

Comment: You should be using arrays instead of objects for you offers, its much easier to filter and to display

Comment: @ukn I a getting this data from api calls and I dont know How to handle. So raised an query for this kind

Comment: @sandysharma you can probably collaborate with this person who has asked the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330391/how-to-combine-two-different-objects-and-view-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var details = [];
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    var item = vlist[0].offers[''+product.productID];
    details.push({
        productName: product.productName,
        ...item
    });
}
```

now you should pass the details to ag-grid.